# Get all characters to the left of final special character + 2 characters after the final special character SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a varchar column with version information in the following format 1.x.y.z where x,y,z can be of any length.I need to limit the length of z to only two if it is more than 2.

For example:`1.345.23.5dfgdfg` should be `1.345.23.5d` and `1.345.23.5` should be `1.345.23.5`

I have the following sql that gives me the required version but is there a simpler way to achieve this?

```
declare @s varchar(50)
set @s = '1.345.23.5dfgdfg'
select  left(@s,len(@s) - (charindex('.',reverse(@s))-1)) + substring(right(@s,charindex('.',reverse(@s))-1),0,3)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your query?

Comment: clumsy and verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

condensing some of the logic:

```
select left(@s,len(@s)+(3-charindex('.',reverse(@s))))
```

---

testing with different values for `@s`:

```
create table t (s varchar(50))
insert into t values 
 ('1.345.23.5dfgdfg')
,('1.345.23.5d')
,('1.345.23.3')

select s, left(s,len(s)+(3-charindex('.',reverse(s))))
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/USIW73651

returns:

```
+------------------+------------------+
|        s         | (No column name) |
+------------------+------------------+
| 1.345.23.5dfgdfg | 1.345.23.5d      |
| 1.345.23.5d      | 1.345.23.5d      |
| 1.345.23.5       | 1.345.23.5       |
+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Nice,works for most cases I tested,will have to wait 4 minutes to accept as answer

Comment: @SqlZim Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the string always has this format, I would be inclined to use:

```
select (case when charindex('.', reverse(@s)) < 3 then @s
             else left(@s, len(@s) - charindex('.', reverse(@s)) + 3)
        end)
```

This is pretty similar to your statement, so you may not think it is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Parsename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) to divide and add back?

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XCSCH44061)

```
declare @s varchar(50)
set @s = '1.345.23.5dfgdfg'

Select PARSENAME ( @s , 4 ) +'.'+
       PARSENAME ( @s , 3 ) +'.'+
       PARSENAME ( @s , 2 ) +'.'+
       left(PARSENAME ( @s , 1 ),2)
```

Usually used in referece to IP address or more specifically as it's intended use:  Fully qualified objects

1 = Object name
2 = Schema name
3 = Database name
4 = Server name